# Populate dynamic columns in sql

Tags: mysql

I have the below sql table tbl_deptExpenses and I want to populate the department as Column:

Table structure:

```
DeptId   Department  Expenses
1        IT           1000
2       Accounting    2000
3       Catering      400
```

What I am trying to achieve is a query to return the below table - where the department values has been changed to Fields:

```
IT     Accounting   Catering
1000    2000         400
```

I have tried the below but does not seem to work:

```
     SELECT    [d.department] = d.department,  
     [Expenses] = d.expenses
 from tbl_deptExpenses d
```

Comment: Search for mysql pivot and mysql conditional aggregation and mysql convert rows to columns.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0):

You may try a pivot query across the entire table:

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN Department = 'IT' THEN Expenses END) AS IT,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Department = 'Accounting' THEN Expenses END) AS Accounting,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Department = 'Catering' THEN Expenses END) AS Catering
FROM tbl_deptExpenses;
```

[image]

### Demo